# Info on metrics

Tags: transactions, stellar-core, ledger, data

Is there any documentation as to what each of the metrics outputted by `stellar-core -c metrics` means?  In particular, I'm interested in determining the number of transactions reviewed by a particular validator since it came online, or the first ledger a validator externalized since coming online, from which I should be able to determine the number of transactions.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: They released the docs in [v10.1.0](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/releases/tag/v10.1.0) in [metrics.md](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/v10.1.0/docs/metrics.md).

---

Unfortunately, there's not much about metrics anywhere in the official docs or repositories besides the [GET metrics/](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/metrics.html) endpoint in the [Horizon API](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/index.html).

I found an [open issue in the repository](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/issues/1710) regarding undocumented metrics values, with a [proposed documentation in an open PR](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/pull/1831) but it has not been merged yet. Maybe when it is properly addressed we'll have more information.

You can see its draft version [here](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/ea0de3f95671312c9e894ba1eb41a68639284372/docs/metrics.md).