# Where can i find info on the meaning of each metric of the core?

Tags: stellar-core

stellar-core has a lot of metrics that can be accessed with /metrics

Is there someplace where I can find out what each metric means?
For example "herder.pending-txs.age2", whats that?

I tried looking at the documentation, and at the code as well, but there are bearly any comments

Comment: Valid question, however (while a different flavor) a very similar question to: https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/867/info-on-metrics

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the docs that now exist on metrics](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/metrics.md)!